# Problems installing Ghost Blog - digital ocean

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, ghost

Keep getting multiple errors for installing and running npm with ghost. I thought it may have been sqlite, but that seems to have been already installed.

```
npm ERR! ghost@0.6.4 start: `node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ghost@0.6.4 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ghost package,  
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ghost
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-20-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"   
npm ERR! cwd /root/ghost 
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/ghost/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your ghost package. So to test it, please start with ghost from scratch:

```
cd ../
mkdir ghosttest
cd ghosttest
wget https://ghost.org/zip/ghost-0.6.4.zip
unzip ghost-0.6.4.zip
npm install --production
npm start
```

If it does not work, try updating node.js and npm to the latest stable version.